# Intervals for periodic function

Tags: trigonometry

Suppose I have a nonlinear periodic function

$$f(\theta) =  A(\theta)\cos \theta + B(\theta)\sin \theta$$

Is it possible to find the interval where the periodic function is positive. I have tried finding the maximum point of the function and then found the intervals where the function is positive, but this fails when the function is having local maximas.

Is there any robust algorithm or method to find the interval where the function is positive? I do not want to split the function into small intervals and checking as it's too computational intensive.

Comment: No my question is if I have a highly nonlinear periodic function. Is there any robust algorithm or method to find the region where the function is positive. I've edited my question.

Comment: The periodic function is already given to me. That is not a choice I can make.

Comment: @carlton_wiss Find the zeros of your function. Provided the functions A and B are smooth, between two successive zeros, the function f does not change sign.